# SOLR multi select faceting, multi-value fields and tagging and excluding filters

Tags: solr

I used the tag and exclude filter functionality to enable a multi select faceting.

These are my example data:

```
    <doc>         
      <field name = "internalid">001</field>     
      <field name = "title">Book 1</field>     
      <field name = "documentType">Book</field>     
      <field name = "categoryTag">Car</field>
      <field name = "categoryTag">Bicycle</field>
   </doc> 
   <doc>       
      <field name = "internalid">002</field>     
      <field name = "title">Book 2</field>     
      <field name = "documentType">Book</field>     
      <field name = "categoryTag">Car</field>
      <field name = "categoryTag">Motobike</field>
   </doc> 
   <doc>         
      <field name = "internalid">003</field>     
      <field name = "title">Book 3</field>     
      <field name = "documentType">Book</field>     
      <field name = "categoryTag">Bicycle</field>
   </doc>
```

My request:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/test_collection/select?q=*:*&facet=true&fq={!tag=categoryTag}categoryTag:Car&facet.field={!ex=categoryTag}categoryTag
```

The response:

```
   "facet_fields":{
      "categoryTags":[
        "Car",2,
        "Bicycle",2,
        "Motobike",1]}
```

So what I would like to achieve is to **pre-calculate** how many results I will get if I add "Bicycle" as an additional OR filter condition. For single-value fields I would just sum "Car(2)+Bicycle(2)=**4**". But here I have an intersection for the first entry which contains the two tags "Car" and "Bicycle". So the correct pre-calculation would be actually "3" here. I googled a lot - but I did not find a proper solution. Would be very pleased for a good approach.

Best regards.

Comment: Make the query you need the count for - the cost would probably be similar. Another option is to use facet.pivot (or sub facets in the JSON Facet API), but that might not give you what you need - it kind of depends on your actual use case.

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot for your input!!

I think Pivot, JSON Facet API and even Group results would not do what is actually required here.

So my solution at this point.

First query:

```
?q=*:*&facet=true&fq={!tag=categoryTag}categoryTag:Car&facet.field={!ex=categoryTag}categoryTag
```

Second query:

```
?q=*:*&facet=true&fq=categoryTag:Car&facet.field=categoryTag
```

First result:

```
"facet_fields":{
      "categoryTag":[
        "Car",2,
        "Bicycle",2,
        "Motobike",1]}
```

Second result:

```
"facet_fields":{
      "categoryTag":[
        "Car",2,
        "Bicycle",1,
        "Motobike",1]}
```

Calculation then for tag "Bicyle":

```
2(Bicycle-Result1)+2(CAR-Result1 - SUM all selected)-1(Bicycle-Result2)=3
```

Calculation then for tag "Motobike":

```
1(Motobike-Result1)+2(CAR-Result1 - SUM all selected)-1(Motobike-Result2)=2
```

This is the only solution I could identify so far.